# Composição não é basicamente injeção de dependência?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, injeção-de-dependência, composição

Li alguns artigos e vi respostas de usuários à essa mesma pergunta que faço mas ainda não entendi.

Um exemplo simples em Python:

```
class Processador: 
      def __init__(self, processador):
          self.processador = processador 

class Ram:
      def __init__(self, RAM):
             self.RAM = RAM

class Placamae:
      def __init__(self, placamae):
           self.placamae = placamae

class computer:
      def __init__(self, processador, placamae, RAM):
           self.processador = processador
           self.placamae = placamae  
           self.ram = ram

New_computer = computer(Processador('intel I7'), Placamae('Asus TUF Gaming'), Ram('DDR4'))
```

O que eu acabei de fazer não pode ser considerado tanto uma injeção de dependência como uma composição de uma classe ?

Comment: Já vi composição feita de uma maneira que gerou o **acoplamento ruim**, onde no construtor da classe, apontava diretamente para classes/objetos externos, onde quem programou, não usou Inj. de dependencias (não passou os objetos no construtor). Para facilitar a escrita de testes de unidade, mative a composição, mas tive que implementar Injec. de depen. para facilitar a criacao de mocks e spy das classes que faziam a composição.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, no meu caso foi em projeto feito Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

A **Composição** é uma técnica em que um objeto contém uma referência para outro objeto e delega parte do seu comportamento para ele. Basicamente o objeto composto é construído a partir de outros objetos, que são combinados para formar um todo funcional. A composição é uma forma de construir objetos complexos a partir de objetos mais simples e reutilizáveis, promovendo a flexibilidade e modularidade do código.

Exemplo:

```
class Motor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.velocidade = 0
    
    def acelerar(self, quantidade):
        self.velocidade += quantidade
    
    def frear(self, quantidade):
        self.velocidade -= quantidade


class Carro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.motor = Motor()
    
    def acelerar(self, quantidade):
        self.motor.acelerar(quantidade)
    
    def frear(self, quantidade):
        self.motor.frear(quantidade)
```

Nesse exemplo, a classe `Carro` utiliza a classe `Motor` para acelerar e frear. A composição ocorre na linha `self.motor = Motor()`, onde a instância do objeto `Motor` é criada dentro da classe `Carro`.

Já a **injeção de dependência** é uma técnica em que as dependências de um objeto são injetadas nele por meio de um mecanismo externo, como um container de inversão de controle (IoC) ou *Inversion of Control*. Em vez de criar as dependências dentro do objeto, ele recebe essas dependências de um contêiner, que é responsável por fornecer e gerenciar essas dependências. A injeção de dependência promove a separação de preocupações e o desacoplamento dos objetos, o que pode facilitar a manutenção e o teste do código.

Exemplo:

```
class Motor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.velocidade = 0
    
    def acelerar(self, quantidade):
        self.velocidade += quantidade
    
    def frear(self, quantidade):
        self.velocidade -= quantidade


class Carro:
    def __init__(self, motor):
        self.motor = motor
    
    def acelerar(self, quantidade):
        self.motor.acelerar(quantidade)
    
    def frear(self, quantidade):
        self.motor.frear(quantidade)
```

Nesse exemplo, a classe `Carro` depende da classe `Motor`, mas em vez de criar uma instância de `Motor` dentro de `Carro`, a instância é passada para `Carro` como um argumento na inicialização. Isso permite que outras instâncias de `Motor` (ou de outras classes que implementam a mesma interface) possam ser injetadas em `Carro` por meio do parâmetro motor. Isso é útil porque, se em algum momento for necessário substituir a implementação de `Motor` por outra, basta criar uma nova instância e injetá-la em `Carro`.

Resumindo, a composição é uma técnica em que objetos são construídos a partir de outros objetos, enquanto a injeção de dependência é uma técnica em que objetos recebem suas dependências de um contêiner externo. Ambas as abordagens podem ser úteis em diferentes situações, dependendo das necessidades específicas do projeto.

Refs.:

- [Injeção de Dependência em Java e Python](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/injecao-de-dependencia-em-java-e-python)
- [Composição em Python: Classe usando Classe](https://www.pythonprogressivo.net/2018/11/Composicao-Classes-Python.html)

Comment: Mas, o que diferencia um componente de uma dependência ?

Comment: Ou seja, a injeção de dependência usa a composição, mas a composição, não necessariamente, usa injeção de dependência. A composição pode ser feita criando o objeto dentro da instância que o utiilza, em vez de ser criado fora dela e então injetado